# Is is possible use the same FileWriter file and write to it from multiple methods?

Tags: java, methods, fileoutputstream, printwriter

I am taking in an input file and an output file from the user and am trying to write to the output file from the main method and the towerOfHanoiMoves method. I tried to pass the output variable as a parameter to the towerOfHanoiMoves method but keep getting an error.

The Error I receive is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Unhandled exception type IOException 
   at TowerofHanoiRecursive.towerOfHanoiMoves(TowerofHanoiRecursive.java:72)
   at TowerofHanoiRecursive.main(TowerofHanoiRecursive.java:41)
```

Is there a way to make this work where I can write to the same output file from two separate methods?

I have tried using PrintWriter but that gave me the same thing. 
I have also tried flushing and closing the outStream in the towerOfHanoiMoves method but that didn't work either. I've also imported all the necessary java.io files but for some reason they did not show up here.

```
public class TowerofHanoiRecursive{


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, EmptyFile,                                      
          FileNotFoundException{
    int n; //number of disks

    String rodLeft = "A", rodRight = "C", rodMiddle = "B";
            FileReader inputStream = null;
            FileWriter outputStream = null;
            BufferedReader str = null;  

   try {
        outputStream = new FileWriter(args[1]); // output file
        inputStream = new FileReader(args[0]);  // input file
            str = new BufferedReader(inputStream);  
            String nextLine; 
            File newFile = new File(args[0]);

     if (newFile.length()==0) { //Tests if input file is empty
       //if file is empty, the EmptyFile exception will be thrown
       throw new EmptyFile("Input file is empty");

       }

     while ((nextLine = str.readLine()) != null) {
        outputStream.write("----------------------------------------"
                + "------------------------\n");
        outputStream.write("Number of Disks in Starting Tower = " 
                + nextLine);
         n = Integer.parseInt(nextLine);

         towerOfHanoiMoves(n, rodLeft, rodRight, rodMiddle, 
              outputStream);

     }

   }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        outputStream.write("Input file not found.);
        outputStream.flush(); 
        if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close();

   }catch (EmptyFile e) {                               
        outputStream.write(e.getMessage());
        outputStream.flush();   
        if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
        if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close();
        str.close();
   } finally { 
        outputStream.write("");
        outputStream.write("\n\nSuccess!);
        outputStream.flush();

        if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
        if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close();
        str.close();
    }

}


  public static void towerOfHanoiMoves(int n, String leftRod, String 
            rightRod, String MidRod, FileWriter outStream) {

    if (n == 1) {
       outStream.write("Move disk 1 from ....");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you care to share the error? Because you absolutely can pass Streams/FileWriter/etc.

Comment: Aside: In the event of one of your exceptions, you close the `outputStream`, but then attempt to write to said now-closed stream in the `finally` block. This approach is likely to be problematic.

Comment: Hi Kevin, this is the error I keep getting: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unhandled exception type IOException

 at TowerofHanoiRecursive.towerOfHanoiMoves(TowerofHanoiRecursive.java:72)
 at TowerofHanoiRecursive.main(TowerofHanoiRecursive.java:41) @KevinO

Comment: And the error also occurs in the towerOfHanoiMoves method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular error is that the `write()` method can throw an `IOException`. As a result, that Exception must be caught or declared.  So, one can modify the `towerOfHannoiMoves` to throw the `IOException`

```
    public static void towerOfHanoiMoves(int n,
        String leftRod,
        String rightRod,
        String MidRod,
        FileWriter outStream)
     throws IOException
```

Another note: there posted code is missing some close quotes. E.g.,

```
outputStream.write("Input file not found.);
```

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it was of assistance. I'd appreciate it if you'd consider accepting the answer.